# 400 Bad request after adding parameter

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart, http-status-code-400, multipartentity

Am getting 400 Bad Request in Retrofit error after adding parameter to my request method

```
@GET("/api/add/remark")
void addRemark(@Header("Cookies") HttpCookie cookie, @Query("tenantId") long tenantId, @Query("userId") long userId, @Query("comment") String commentJson, @Query("file") MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity, Callback<CreationResponse> callback);
```

this is how at my server receives it

```
@RequestMapping("add/remark")
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_SITE_USER","ROLE_FIELDUSER"})
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public @ResponseBody
CreationResponse addRemarkController1(@RequestParam String comment,@RequestParam Integer userId,@RequestParam long tenantId,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

If the multipart parameter is ommitted on both sides am able to send remarks without any fail.

this is how my MultipartEntity adds image 
`MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entity.addBinaryBody("file", input, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),photosPath.getName());`

Comment: you are sending file with GET?

Comment: yes i am is it not supposed to be ?

Comment: I never saw a multipart request using GET method. I may be wrong also. Are you able to try this request successfully in postman or any other rest client?

Comment: no i havent tried anything like that yet

Comment: than i am sure you cannot achieve this using get method.

Comment: we tried it on postman client thank you.. we were able to get response in it